# Web scraper encounters issue grabbing website randomly (GitHub)

Tags: python, github, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

**Update**: *It looks like it has something to do with GitHub and the number of calls.  I guess the Sessions looks a bit suspicious.  I've since incorporated Selenium which is a bit better but still has a connection issue on occasion.  If anyone knows of a foolproof method, that would be great.*

I'm currently coding a web scraper with very limited functionality as of right now.  Currently, it is acting as a notification system just to check if a repository has been updated in GitHub.

The current issue I'm running into is that, sometimes the scrape works exactly as intended and sometimes it doesn't.  when it's working, it grabs the correct HTML via Beautiful Soup and searches for the "relative-time"/"datetime" tags. There should always be at least 3 with how my repository is currently set up.

However, sometimes when running the exact same code (no changes), it won't retrieve the same HTML meaning that something with the website retrieval went wrong.  I have a suspicion that it's to do with the authentication or session, which may be *timing out*.

The caveat is that I'm trying to avoid using inspection tool automation (meaning having a script with cookie/header data) as I would ideally want this to be given to a user where they only have to enter a name/password.  I don't want to retrieve all the cookies/headers unless there's no other option.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import datetime


#Return a Soup Value using a Response
def initialize_soup(resp):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'html.parser')
    return soup

#Get the most recent date the repository was updated
def get_last_updated(bs):

    #look for relative-time tag
    time_var = bs.find('relative-time')
    string = str(time_var)

    #isolate down to datetime param
    s = string.find("datetime")
    value = s

    #Grab static values to create a date-time value
    date_string = string[value + 10:(value + 10 + 10)]
    time_string = string[value + 21:(value + 21 + 5)]
    
    #Concatentate into new value
    last_updated_string = date_string + ' ' + time_string + ':00'

    #If the web scraper bugs out, it'll return a 'default' datetime so that code doesn't 
    #break
    if len(last_updated_string) < 15:
        last_updated_string = "1900-01-01 12:00:00"
        print("CONNECTION ERROR")

    last_updated = datetime.datetime.strptime(last_updated_string, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    return last_updated

#compare dates to see if GitHub has updated
def is_updated(old_datetime, new_date_time):
    if old_datetime < new_date_time:
        print("GitHub updated")
    else:
        print("Not Updated")



login_url = "https://github.com/session"

login = 'login value omitted here'
password = 'password omitted here'

with requests.session() as s:
    req = s.get(login_url).text
    html = BeautifulSoup(req,"html.parser")
    token = html.find("input", {"name": "authenticity_token"}). attrs["value"]
    time = html.find("input", {"name": "timestamp"}).attrs["value"]
    timeSecret = html.find("input", {"name": "timestamp_secret"}). attrs["value"]
payload = {
    "authenticity_token": token,
    "login": login,
    "password": password,
    "timestamp": time,
    "timestamp_secret": timeSecret
}

res = s.post(login_url, data = payload)
repository_url = "working repository link"

#get the first date time value (we'll use this to compare dates on an interval)
r = s.get(repository_url)
bs = initialize_soup(r)
prev_dt = get_last_updated(bs)

## These lines just test to see if the code is working/when it's not working
#print(bs.find_all("datetime"))
#print(bs)

#On an interval, check the repository's last updated date and compare against old date.
import time
while True:
    new_response = s.get(repository_url)
    new_soup = initialize_soup(new_response)
    new_dt = get_last_updated(new_soup)

    if prev_dt < new_dt:
        print("There's an update on GitHub waiting for you!")
        #if we have a new update to report, update the values
        prev_dt = new_dt
    else:
        print("Not updated -- Testing Purposes Only")
    time.sleep(30)
```

Naming conventions aren't fantastic so I apologize for any readability issues.  If anyone knows why the scrape works intermittently, that would be much appreciated.

**Update**
I was actually able to throw the returned HTML (when the code errors) into beautify and see what was coming out.

It looks like when this is happening, GitHub is returning an error on their page saying:
"Failed to load latest commit information"

Does anyone know why this is and how I could avoid?